# How to send an HTTP request using Telnet

Tags: http, telnet

How to get a web page's content using [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)?

For example, the content of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`.

Comment: Example `telnet telehack.com`.  [List of examples](http://www.telnet.org/htm/places.htm)

Comment: This comment/example, is far better than the highest rated answer - if using a device which doesn't have dns (such as some of the cisco routers I'm setting up) just nslookup the IP first, then connect.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

telnet ServerName 80

---

```
GET /index.html↵
↵
```

*↵ means 'return', you need to hit return twice*

Comment: You must add two line breaks after `GET /index.html`, otherwise, it wouldn't work. **The end of the header section is indicated by an empty field(line), resulting in the transmission of two consecutive CR-LF pairs.** — [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

Comment: if you want to automate this: `{ echo "GET /"; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 80` (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts/7021653#7021653)

Comment: HTTP/1.0 is really not necessary? The HTTP Specification does not mark it as opcional, but most servers seems to work without it. Is this a kind of undocumented behavior, or it is documented elsewhere?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz: IIRC it's interpreted then as "HTTP v0.9".

Answer (score 125):

You could do

```
telnet stackoverflow.com 80
```

And then paste

```
GET /questions HTTP/1.0
Host: stackoverflow.com


# add the 2 empty lines above but not this one
```

Here is a transcript

```
$ telnet stackoverflow.com 80
Trying 151.101.65.69...
Connected to stackoverflow.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /questions HTTP/1.0
Host: stackoverflow.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

Comment: Hrm, it worked just fine for me (and the 'Accept' header wasn't necessary either).

If you execute it quickly enough (and with the same headers as a real browser) then it would be literally impossible to tell the difference between a CLI request and one from a browser. The only way to discriminate would be to look at a greater context (e.g. follow-up requests or the lack thereof, or their timing, but even then it's not deterministic as a user might use an extension or setting to disable the loading of external resources).

Comment: There were extra spaces at the beginning of the lines that caused a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` response. I fixed it and included a transcript. Cheers.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 doesn't work for me. Shouldn't it be HTTP/1.1 ?

Comment: @therealak12 Both protocols are in common use. It would be unusual to find a general-purpose server which refuses to serve 1.0 clients, but a bespoke server for a limited purpose might well have such restrictions, though it seems more likely to be an implementor oversight than a calibrated decision.

Answer (score 57):

For posterity, your question was how to send an http request to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`. The real answer is: you cannot with telnet, cause this is an https-only reachable url.

So, you might want to use `openssl` instead of `telnet`, like this for instance

```
$ openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443
...
---
GET /questions HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

This will give you the https response.

Comment: or `nc --ssl stackoverflow.com 443` if [tag:netcat] is installed

Comment: If the server insists on CR/LF line termination (as per the HTTP protocol spec, but frequently ignored) add `-crlf` to the options.

Comment: @user4104817 On macOS `nc` can't do that, but `brew install nmap` provides `ncat` command with that option

Comment: Posterity thanks you.

Answer (score 15):

To somewhat expand on earlier answers, there are a few complications.

`telnet` is not particularly scriptable; you might prefer to use `nc` (aka `netcat`) instead, which handles non-terminal input and signals better.

Also, unlike `telnet`, `nc` actually allows SSL (and so `https` instead of `http` traffic -- you need port 443 instead of port 80 then).

There is a difference between HTTP 1.0 and 1.1.  The recent version of the protocol requires the `Host:` header to be included in the request on a separate line after the `POST` or `GET` line, and to be followed by an empty line to mark the end of the request headers.

The HTTP protocol requires carriage return / line feed line endings. Many servers are lenient about this, but some are not. You might want to use

```
printf "%s\r\n" \
    "GET /questions HTTP/1.1" \
    "Host: stackoverflow.com" \
    "" |
nc --ssl stackoverflow.com 443
```

If you fall back to HTTP/1.0 you don't always need the `Host:` header, but many modern servers require the header anyway; if multiple sites are hosted on the same IP address, the server doesn't know from `GET /foo HTTP/1.0` whether you mean `http://site1.example.com/foo` or `http://site2.example.net/foo` if those two sites are both hosted on the same server (in the absence of a `Host:` header, a HTTP 1.0 server might just default to a different site than the one you want, so you don't get the contents you think you are getting).

The HTTPS protocol is identical to HTTP in these details; the only real difference is in how the session is set up initially.

For what it's worth, [Telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) was once a fairly ubiquitous protocol for unencrypted remote terminal access (standard port number 23). When encrypted remote access over SSH (port 22) became available in 1995, it basically caused a mass extinction of Telnet servers, but the client software still exists, and allows you to easily talk to any text-based server, such as an HTTP server (or an SMTP server, or an FTP server, or etc).

The Telnet protocol has some non-textual control sequences which of course an HTTP server will not transmit most of the time, though it could happen by accident e.g. if you triggered it to send random binary data, in which case the client could intercept the control codes and corrupt the data.

[Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) has no such protocol-specific features, and is purely a tool for putting bytes on the wire. In addition to its simpler and more robust general-purpose design, it has features to allow you to control specific behaviors of the raw socket from the command line, and to control details of its interactive behavior for scripting etc. Unlike the Telnet client, it also allows you to set up a listening socket, so a simple server.

(On some platforms, there are multiple Netcat implementations, some of which are less featureful than others. If you can't find `netcat`, maybe look for `nc` or `ncat`. There is also a separate tool [`socat`](https://manpages.org/socat) which can be useful for network troubleshooting.)

Comment: Here is a one-liner with netcat: `{ echo "GET / HTTP/1.1"; echo "Host: example.com"; echo; sleep 1; } | ncat --ssl example.com 443`

Comment: I don't really see any advantage over `printf`. Maybe the `sleep` helps in some situations.

Comment: I think it does not matter, I guess `printf` can do more things but `echo` is enough in this case. I just thought it can be useful to share a one-liner with netcat.

Comment: Awesome. A little tweak on MacOs Catalina was using `ncat` instead, because `nc` doesn't provide `--ssl`.

Comment: If that counts as a one-liner, the `printf` version can certainly be folded to a single line simply by removing the newlines, too.

Comment: The `echo` example also fails to include the DOS carriage returns before every newline. It can be worked around with `echo -e` but again that begs the question why you try to avoid the simpler, more elegant and portable `printf`