# Telnet connection on localhost Refused

Tags: php, python, telnet

**EDIT:**

I want to `telnet` into my web server on `localhost`, and request my `php` file from command line:

I have:

1) cd'd into the directory I want to serve, namely "`/www`" (`hello.php` is here)

2) run a server at directory www: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

3) `telnet localhost 80`

but "connection is refused". what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an HTTP request using Telnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772355/how-to-send-an-http-request-using-telnet)

Comment: im confused as what you want to achieve.

Comment: @metatoaster where http request on this  question? Don't write google result !  Yes ! but, if a service run on in a thread, when thread is ended service will be stop or freeze. you want serve forever, need set as local service and use via control script.  But don't forget you require a strong threading manager for all security bug..

Comment: @data-garden your page a `PHP`, how to serve it with python ?

Comment: @dsgdfg how do I serve it then?

Comment: [here smilar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235876/python-simplehttpserver-with-php) try on console check if is work. @data_garden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to connect to a wrong port. Check with `netstat -lntp` which port is your http server listening on. The process will be listed as `python/pid_number`.

Comment: as server runs, I get `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 `. is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, in that case you want to run `telnet localhost 8000`, not `80`

Answer (score -2):

If you're using Linux then try this:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
GET /hello.php
```