# Telnet inner-workings: Is telnet server necessary if client connects to an HTTP server?

Tags: telnet, tcp

One way to quickly test the first-order functionality of a web server is to use the application layer tool Telnet, e.g. [How to send an HTTP request using Telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772355/how-to-send-an-http-request-using-telnet).

This is the usage I am most familiar with, but today I learned there is such a thing as a Telnet server: https://askubuntu.com/questions/668725/how-can-the-telnet-service-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-be-enabled, which listens on the well-known port 23 and can be used (though not usually, due to its lack of security) as a remote shell.

I am trying to understand if a Telnet server is necessary if I use it to connect to an HTTP server on port 80, e.g.,
`telnet 192.168.0.5 80`

Does the Telnet client first connect to the telnet server on port 23, then somehow the server's Telnet process then establish a connection to port 80 on localhost? Or does the client directly connect to the HTTP server (or some other TCP/IP server, for that matter) on 80, without need the Telnet server to be present at all?

I could not immediately find a piece of Telnet documentation that explains how Telnet works in this regard; their scarcity might be attributed to Telnet's lack of security...

Comment: no it should not use the telnet server, it connects directly to the host/port mentioned, the telnet server is needed if you want to use telnet as a remote shell (AFAIK) like login, then **dir**, then execute other ms-dos commands or run other applications and configuration that can be done through a regular **cmd**