# OPTIONS request using Telnet for Apache Server

Tags: apache, http, telnet

The Problem:
[image]

I am really new to Apache and HTTP requests and have been trying to get the OPTIONS method to work to no avail, GET works and returns the contents of a specified file but OPTIONS does not work at all. I have enabled WebDAV and the apache server is running, I am connecting to the server using telnet.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You should check the syntax of your requests. See here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772355/how-to-send-an-http-request-using-telnet