# telnet redis bash script

Tags: bash, redis, telnet

How can I extract the output from a telnet command on a remote redis-server in a bash script.

I would do:

```
telnet remote-redis-ip 6379 
LRANGE mylist 0 -1
```

And save the result in a variable. How can I reach this goal under a bash script?

Thanks,

Comment: To save a command output in a variable, do `var=$(command)`.

Comment: Yeah I know that but if I try: var="$(telnet remote-redis-ip 6379 | echo "LRANGE mylist 0 -1")" its doesn't works

Comment: Mmmm the echo after the pipe doesn't have any sense. What do you want to do? What's the output of `telnet remote-redis-ip 6379` and what's `LRANGE mylist 0 -1`?

Comment: Ouput of telnet is "connected" and LRANGE mylist 0 -1 return an IP list.

Comment: OK so you want to connect to redis through telnet and then perform a command. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7013137/1983854, then

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this

```
RET=`telnet remote-redis-ip 6379 << EOF
LRANGE mylist 0 -1
EOF`

echo $RET
```

and I think using expect [automating telnet session using bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts) post by fedorqui will be better