# Terminate Curl Telnet session in bashscript

Tags: bash, curl, telnet

Working on automating telnet connectivity from various hosts running the script from specified host with `curl` telnet call.

However as are aware for telnet once we get connected status for any hosts we have to pass an escape character to terminate the telnet sessions, but in bash script I need to terminate the session as soon as we get Connected/Refused response from the target endpoint or after some seconds of running the telnet session .

PFB Script where telnet connectivity is checked through Curl call, so I need is there anyway in `curl` that we can terminate the telnet session in `curl` as soon as we get the response or terminate the session in some milliseconds/seconds.

Code:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    HOSTS='LPDOSPUT00100 LPDOSPUT00101'
     for S in ${HOSTS}
      do
         echo "Checking Connectivity From Host : ${S}"
         echo ""
         ssh -q apigee@${S} "curl -v telnet://${TargetEndPoint}:${Port}"
     done
```

Answer (score 4):

You could run it in the `timeout` command to make it terminate after a certain amount of time.

```
ssh -q apigee@"$S" "timeout 5s curl -v telnet://${TargetEndPoint}:${Port}"
```

would terminate it after 5 seconds if it hadn't already exited on its own.

Perhaps `curl` isn't the right tool for this job though.  Have you considered using `nc` instead?

```
ssh -q apigee@"$S" "nc -z ${TargetEndPoint} $Port"
```

will likely do what you want.