# Telnet to Gogo shell works well but telnet with bash script returns connection closed by foreign host

Tags: bash, shell, telnet, gogo-shell

I am trying to use bash script to do some works automatically with telnet ( actually to interact with Felix Gogo shell). Simply they are:

```
telnet localhost 11311
command 1
command 2
...
```

I followed these instruction:

[automating telnet session using bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts)

The script I am using is: ~/telwork.sh

```
echo 'open localhost 11311'
sleep 1
echo 'command 1'
sleep 1
echo 'command 2'
sleep 1
echo 'command 3'
...
```

Unfortunately `./telwork.sh | telnet` will exist during the execution with `Connection closed by foreign host.`  However, if I manually do the works one by one in the console, everything works well. The same problem occurs in both mac osx and rhel.

I have made some search on the internet and stackoverflow but it seems that the answers are always talk about authentication. But I can login to the Gogo shell by typing `telnet localhost 11311`.

Therefore I post this problem for your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you actually running your script with expect?

Comment: I run the script by `./telwork.sh | telnet` in bash. It usually runs normally upto command 2 or command 3 and returns `connection closed by foreign host`