# Find device information from IP address

Tags: port, telnet, iot, port-scanning, shodan

I have a list of IP addresses and they are probably of the IOT devices. How can I figure out the OS of the device(I only have its IP address) using any script/tool/service ? Any help would be immensely appreciated. I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: Kindly care to provide reason for downvoting the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this (for an example):

- [automating telnet session using bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013137/automating-telnet-session-using-bash-scripts)

you can try to write your own telnet script (open session, send some command and retrieve information that you need).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Shodan. Shodan includes the operating system when possible and also gives you a lot of additional information to decide whether it's an IoT device or not. Here's some sample code in Python to get you started:

```
from shodan import Shodan

# Setup the API connection
api = Shodan("YOUR API KEY") # Get it from https://account.shodan.io

# Lookup the IP information
host = api.host("66.96.212.7")

# If Shodan was able to identify the operating system then it will have
# an "os" property
if 'os' in host and host['os']:
    print(host['os'])

# You can also look at the list of ports running on the IP to determine
# whether it's an IoT device
print(host['ports'])

# Or you can look at the "tags" property as that sometimes includes an "iot" tag
print(host['tags'])
```