# How to Automate pressing [ENTER] to continue in bash script

Tags: bash, automation, interactive

I have a bash script that helps install a few applications automatically.

One app requests that I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to continue, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel.

How can I automate my script to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when that prompt comes up?

Comment: `echo -e '\n' | your_command_or_script` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you!  I think that did the trick.

Comment: @RobertSeaman `echo -e '\n'` is pointless and non-POSIX. Use `{ echo;echo; } | command` alone.

Answer (score 4):

For simple enter or confirmation, consider using the `yes` command:

```sh
yes '' | command_or_script
```

For automating more complex interactions, consider using `expect`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013379/7939871