# Run shell script in non interactive mode in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to execute this script https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh in a Dockerfile.

```
# I have already downloaded the file
RUN bash Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

When I launch it I got this error:

```
RUN bash Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh:
#0 0.411 
#0 0.411 Welcome to Miniconda3 py38_23.1.0-1
#0 0.411 
#0 0.411 In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
#0 0.411 agreement.
#0 0.411 Please, press ENTER to continue
#0 0.411 >>>
```

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198641/how-to-automate-pressing-enter-to-continue-in-bash-script) that you can add `yes ''` before your script to "auto confirm"

```
# I have already downloaded the file
RUN yes | bash Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

But when I do this I got:

```
RUN yes '' | bash Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh                                                                                                                                                               6.5s
 => => # >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => => # >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => => # >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => => # >>> Please answer 'yes' or 'no':'                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => => # >>> Please answer 'yes' or                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 => => # [output clipped, log limit 200KiB/s reached]
```

Is there a way to tell bash to run this script in a non interactive mode and accept default parameters by default ?

Comment: Can you edit the script to not `read` input?  The bash interpreter itself doesn't have any notion of "default parameters" in response to interactive questions like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do:

```
RUN bash Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
```

See `Miniconda3-py38_23.1.0-1-Linux-x86_64.sh -h`

Answer (score 0):

> `RUN yes '' | ...`

That invocation of `yes` produces empty strings.

```
% yes '' | head -n 1
```

You want it to say 'yes' so you should actually specify that.

```
% yes 'yes' | head -n 1                                                                                                                                                                   
yes
```